# Retrieve custom field value in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Any one help me  for retrieving  value from customn field in wp_post table
i ADDED a filed called rating in wp-post table .how retirve value from that
critical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using

[get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

```
$meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```

or

[get_post_custom](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom)

```
 get_post_custom($post_id);
```

### According to your comment:

Edit

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'your_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: it is not working ....can you post the code for retireing a field called rating in the wp_post table not in meta table ...please

Comment: @user912238: whats your post type,I think your question is wrong change it as "Custom post" not "custom field"

Comment: actaully i want ot include rating to a post  and view it on the user side .that s y i said custom field

Comment: @user912238:you didn't answer my question whats your **post_type** in  wp_post table

Comment: what u ment by post_type?i m new to wordpress

Comment: @user912238:please go to your database and check the table ** wp_post**.There should be a column  **post_type**.in your particular post what post type is used.where did you add rating in admin please give clear details . are u used default custom field in wp. or any plugin or what have u done.can you figure out where its stored.

Comment: i added a filed called rating in wp_post table.the value iin post-type field is post

Comment: Sorry need to check out now.SO Peoples will help you .please edit your question and add all details in question

Comment: @user912238: grab mail address from profile page then come to chat. try to help